# Displaying custom module as XML page in Drupal 7

Tags: xml, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

Is it possible to display a "content block" as XML and then be able to access it using a URL (e.g www.mywebsite.com/modules/mymodule/xml)?

I have a content block setup at the moment but instead of displaying it as a paragraph in the current Drupal template or page I would like to access it by using something similar to the URL above.

Thanks,
Steven.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a view exporting to XML using Views and https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export.